# I want to store the private key inside my java project

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

In my java project I want to implement encryption/ decryption operations. I decided for the RSA algorithm with Cipher.
I do not want to generate a new key pair. I want to use a specific one. 
Users owning the jar may not have access to the private key and since the git repository is public, it also may not appear directly in the code.
My first thought was to put it in a text file in my resources and add the file to my gitignore. But apparently, resource files can easily be found, readable inside the jar.

I hope you understand my problem now.

Help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Can you provide a code example of something you have tried?

Comment: You need to rethink and redesign your scheme. Trying to store a hard-coded private key in client-side code/apps is doomed to failure.

Comment: _I want to store the private key inside my java project_ <-- Trust me, you really don't.  What do you actually want to do, where you think this is the solution?

Comment: Systems that store private keys (of asymetric encryption systems) usually encrypt them with a symmetric encryption algorithm (i.e. AES). When a user wants to make use of the private key, the user needs to have the key decrypted first. E.g. when providing the SSL cert's private key for an Apache server, you are asked to enter a pass phrase to protect it. Is this a solution for you?

Comment: @rileyjsumner No, I'm still thinking about how to do this. The code should not be the problem.

at others:
I want to protect the user data when persisting them to a file on their disk. But at the same time, I want to be able to read them when I send them to me, which also happens inside the application. I thought this to be the best or easiest way. I have chosen RSA because it is the only crypto-algorithm I'm familiar with. I think AES could also do it, but don't I have the same problem with the password as with the private key? Where would I save it?

Comment: Encryption is done with the public key, decryption is done with the private key. So you only have to distribute the public key (in order that your app can encrypt the data sent to you), and you keep the private key at your side where you can decrypt the received data.

Comment: @Heri The application also needs access to the decrypted data :)

Comment: Couldn't you store the key-pair in an environment variable and reference it's value in your code?

Comment: @davedwards but users would be able to get my private key :/

Comment: so why not do similar to as [Heri suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53125491/i-want-to-store-the-private-key-inside-my-java-project?noredirect=1#comment93148044_53125491) and create a public key and passphrase that you can distribute in your java project, which the users can use them to generate their own private keys, as described in this article https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/ssh-keys

Comment: @davedwards What is the difference to my idea of distributing the private key (and public key) with my java project?

Comment: @the difference is my idea wouldn't include your private key in the project, the users would generate their private keys from public key and passphrase in your project, whereas your idea would actually include the private key in the project, leaving no security

Comment: @davedwards  Would the application still be able to decrypt data without having the private key?

Comment: no I don't believe it would be able to @primarykey123

Comment: Why are you doing this client side and not server side...?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I guess I wanted to avoid the request every time the application wants to decrypt data. Maybe I should create the key pair locally and send me the private key. But where would I store the private key on the user's computer to make it the most safe for the user?

Comment: You could randomly generate an AES data key and use that to encrypt the data (preferably use authenticated encryption such as GCM). Then you encrypt (or wrap) that key using two public keys: one for the private key you have at the server and one for your application. The one for the application can be stored in any key store, preferably a *system key store* to stay secure.